# What is an ndarray of shape () returned after np.squeeze from shape (1,1)?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm calculating a cost function for a NN.  I do a numpy.squeeze on a (1,1) answer that I get from numpy.dot.  I then get an ndarray of shape (0,1).

What is an ndarray of shape () and how does an ndarray of shape (1,) differ from one of shape (5)?

Comment: Try`cost.item()` or `cost[()]`

Comment: Hint: You can drop quite a few parentheses for increased readability: `cost2 = -1.0 / m * (np.dot(Y, np.log(A).T) + np.dot(1.0 - Y, np.log(1.0 - A).T))`

Answer (score 3):

- An ndarray of shape `(1, 1)` is something like `[[3]]`, like a 1x1 matrix.
- An ndarray of shape `(1,)` is something like `[3]`, like a vector of size 1.
- An ndarray of shape `()`, a.k.a a scalar, is something like `3`.

The difference is subtle because due to broadcasting rules scalars and arrays can usually be combined without problem, but you cannot index a scalar, while you can index a vector of size 1 or a matrix of size 1x1. On the other hand, scalars can generally be used like primitive Python values such as `int` or `float`. If you don't want to have a scalar you can either pass an `axis` parameter to [`np.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to make sure that some dimension is not squeezed or use [`np.atleast_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) to make sure that whatever you pass has at least one dimension. You can also check if something is a scalar with [`np.isscalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isscalar.html).

Answer (score 2):

`dot` with a (1,n) and (n,1) produces a (1,1) array:

```
In [1221]: x = np.ones((3,1))
In [1222]: xx = np.dot(x.T,x)
In [1223]: xx.shape
Out[1223]: (1, 1)
In [1224]: xx
Out[1224]: array([[ 3.]])
```

`item` can be used to extract that value from the array:

```
Out[1227]: 3.0
In [1228]: type(_)
Out[1228]: float
```

You can also select the item by indexing, though the `type` will be different:

```
In [1229]: xx[0,0]
Out[1229]: 3.0
In [1230]: type(_)
Out[1230]: numpy.float64
```

For many purposes the difference between a `float` and `np.float64` doesn't matter.

`squeeze` removes all size 1 dimensions.  In this case the result is a 0d array.  `item` still works.  Indexing works too, using the correct size of index (i.e. a tuple of length 0):

```
In [1231]: xx0 = np.squeeze(xx)
In [1232]: xx0.shape
Out[1232]: ()
In [1233]: xx0.item()
Out[1233]: 3.0
In [1234]: xx0[()]
Out[1234]: 3.0
In [1235]: type(_)
Out[1235]: numpy.float64
```

The class inheritance for a `np.float64` is:

```
In [1236]: _.__mro__
Out[1236]: 
(numpy.float64,
 numpy.floating,
 numpy.inexact,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 float,
 object)
```

So `isinstance` float will still return true

```
In [1237]: isinstance(xx0.item(),float)
Out[1237]: True
In [1238]: isinstance(xx0[()],float)
Out[1238]: True
In [1239]: isinstance(xx[0,0],float)
Out[1239]: True
```

I wouldn't depend that for all numpy dtypes.