# Python isinstance() of float failing assertion test

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, precision, isinstance

**Background:**
I've been completing a course in machine learning and neural networks, and in the following where I experienced a problem, we're required to compute the cost function. There are two ways to do so by applying a np.multiply and np.sum OR by np.dot. I've called these cost1 and cost2, respectively in the example. They produce the same result.

**Question:**
My issue is that the function (which is already completed for me) asserts that the cost is a float using isinstance(). The first method produces a value which passes this test, and the second does not. However, when I print both values, and their associated dtypes, they both appear to be floats, although cost2 has greater precision. Why does cost2 fail the assertion test?

The Code:

```
def compute_cost(A2, Y, parameters):
    """ 
    Computes the cross-entropy cost given in equation (13)

    Arguments:
    A2 -- The sigmoid output of the second activation, of shape (1, number of examples)
    Y -- "true" labels vector of shape (1, number of examples)
    parameters -- python dictionary containing your parameters W1, b1, W2 and b2

    Returns:
    cost -- cross-entropy cost given equation (13)
    """

    m = Y.shape[1] # number of example

    # Compute the cross-entropy cost
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    logprobs = np.multiply(np.log(A2), Y)
    cost1 = -np.sum(logprobs)
    cost2 = -np.dot(np.log(A2), Y.T)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    cost1 = np.squeeze(cost1)     # makes sure cost is the dimension we expect. 
    cost2 = np.squeeze(cost2)     # E.g., turns [[17]] into 17 


    # Troubleshooting
    print(cost1.dtype,cost2.dtype)
    print(cost1,cost2)

    assert(isinstance(cost1, float))
    assert(isinstance(cost2, float))

    return cost1


A2, Y_assess, parameters = compute_cost_test_case()
print("cost = " + str(compute_cost(A2, Y_assess, parameters)))
```

Output:

```
float64 float64
0.692685886972 0.6926858869721941
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-92a25de13cb3> in <module>()
  1 A2, Y_assess, parameters = compute_cost_test_case()
  2 
----> 3 print("cost = " + str(compute_cost(A2, Y_assess, parameters)))

<ipython-input-83-411aa6cb57b7> in compute_cost(A2, Y, parameters)
 30 
 31     assert(isinstance(cost1, float))
---> 32     assert(isinstance(cost2, float))
 33 
 34     return cost1

AssertionError:
```

Comment: Show the output of `print(type(cost1), type(cost2))`

Comment: The numpy floats are not subclasses of Python float.

Comment: np.squeeze will return an array from an multi-dimensional array. So your cost2.dtype will still return the dtype of array members, isinstance will still see it as an array.

Comment: If `cost1` is a single item array, or `np.float64`, then `cost1.item()` will be a Python float.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, let me start from the beginning.

**First**, and it is not about the question you asked for, but it is for the scientific secretariat. The `np.dot()` is not always equal to `np.sum and np.multiply`, in theory, they are equal, but in regard to the cost function calculation, they won't be the same, as the calculations of `np.dot` will differ from matrix to vector, not to mention that it will give you an error because of dimensions mismatch. So to be on the safe side, use multiply then the sum functions, and you can check this post for more information about this matter. [Python implementation of the  cost function in logistic regression: why dot multiplication in one expression but element-wise multiplication in another](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22470/python-implementation-of-cost-function-in-logistic-regression-why-dot-multiplic)

**Second**, and this is your original question, to get into the problem, you should print all the information about cost1 and cost2.
For example, after calculating the cost equation with `keepdims = True`, you will find that `cost.shape = ()`, `cost.dtype = float64` and `type(cost) = numpy.ndarray` which is a `scalar` and *that is your problem here*.
The function `squeeze` can successfully make a dimensional reduction to the point for example `[[.364]]` will be `.364`. However, `.364` will be of type `numpy.ndarray`.

So, to convert from `scalar` to float, you can just do this

**Solution:**

```
cost = np.asscalar(cost)    # make sure to convert scalar with shape () to normal float
```

And hence, *your assert will surely work fine*.

You can check this question [How to convert singleton array to a scalar value in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157742/how-to-convert-singleton-array-to-a-scalar-value-in-python/35157822) and this one too [What is a ndarray of shape () returned after np.squeeze from shape (1,1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862778/what-is-an-ndarray-of-shape-returned-after-np-squeeze-from-shape-1-1)